# selected area to cut an image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

Hi I would do the selected area to cut an image on `picturebox` control.

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Rectangle rect;
    private Pen p;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.p == null)
            this.p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, 200, 200, 200), 5);
        if (this.rect.Width > 0)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(this.p, this.rect);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.X < this.rect.X)
        {
            this.rect.Width = this.rect.X - e.X;
            this.rect.X = e.X;
        }
        else
        {
            this.rect.Width = e.X - this.rect.X;
        }

        if (e.Y < this.rect.Y)
        {
            this.rect.Height = this.rect.Y - e.Y;
            this.rect.Y = e.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            this.rect.Height = e.Y - this.rect.Y;
        }

        this.Invalidate(this.rect);

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.rect.X = e.X;
        this.rect.Y = e.Y;
    }

}
```

}

It returns an error here:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Why?

thanks for all replies ;p

Comment: I guess nullpointer exception in the second line in OnPaint for this.rect....

Comment: @rene it's a structure so it can't be null, it will default to Rectangle.Empty with all properties set to 0.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard As I said, a guess...wrong...programming is an exact science...proven again. At least I'm not the only one happily guessing...

Comment: @rene no sweat.. until Oskar gets back we're all just guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this optimized code, if you still get error post it here (edit your original question) and we'll see.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.p == nulll)
      this.p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, 200, 200, 200), 5);
   if (this.rect.Width > 0)
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(this.p, this.rect);
}
```

Comment: ok man i solved my problems by my own...i replaced: `this.Invalidate(this.rect);` with `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` or `pictureBox1.Refresh();` for refresh an image region....so this work well...but i have another question...how to do the animation when it's drawing this resizable rectangle on my picture?so now it works...i must click on the image and then stretch for set the rectangle's size, when i left the mouse button click the rectangle was drawing...why it didn't refresh always...?

Comment: @Oskar you probably need to handle the `MouseMove` event as well and call the `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` in there too. By default it won't auto refresh itself.

Comment: hi it's me again ;p...how can i save the initial position of my mouse...and final position when the mouse's button released...i'm asking for because i'm just trying to use the mouseclick event for it, but it doesn't work well...i have the following code:
`private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
       
            button1.Text = "X: " + Convert.ToString(e.X);
            button2.Text = "Y: " + Convert.ToString(e.Y);
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;

        }`

Comment: @Oskar you're already saving the position into `this.rect.X` and `this.rect.Y` in the `mousedown` event... click is actually `mouseup` following `mousedown`. What exactly you mean by "initial position"?

Comment: so when the picturebox detect the mouseclick event so this is the initial position when begins the first vertex of my rectangle...and then i need the final position when the rectangle ends...so when my control detect mouse button released...thx for your patience but i'm  still newbie in .net ;p

Comment: @Oskar so what you want is that first click will act like your current `pictureBox1_MouseDown` event and second click will act like the `pictureBox1_MouseUp` event?

Comment: hmmm...i dont understand too well, i dont know what you want to say me...so how can i do what i want...?so how can i capture mouse's position...when i'm clicking on picturebox and then when i released the button...which event i have to use?

Comment: @Oskar problem is I don't know what **you** want. Click contains within itself the action of releasing the button so your last sentence is logically meaningless. Think again what exactly is your goal and edit your original question with your exact need so that others can come and help as well.

Comment: ok...enter on facebook...go to ur profile...then set your avatar...when you chosen ur picture you can crop itself...so i would to do the same thing...so when i have setted my rectangle on the picture this is the part of image which i would to crop...
`private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
   Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
   Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
   bmpImage.PixelFormat);
   return (Image)(bmpCrop);
}`

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't dispose of the Graphics object that is passed as part of the PaintEventArgs.  That is probably what is causing your issue.

Comment: The Golden Rule: only dispose objects that you created yourself.

Answer (score 0):

what is the error?

you are leaking Pen's. For every paint message you create a new pen and throw the old without disposing.

Off the top of my head I can't remember if you should dispose of the graphics object you get from the event args

Comment: Shouldn't the `Pens` get garbage collected?

Comment: GC will get there eventually, however I suspect for ultimately unmanaged resources like Pens, it will be 2 pass as the finialiser will need to be called first.  Pens/Brushes/Graphics/etc are a limited resource. You want to be deterministic over their lifetime. You should create the pen early on (c'tor or Load) and then Dispose of it in your Dispose method which you *will* have implemented because you are using these limited resources.